# pytorch не видит cuda

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, cuda, pytorch

Я совсем новичок в этой теме и начал читать книгу. Тк на моем пк есть GPU, я захотел использовать cuda для работы с pytorch, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу его верно установить.

```
>>> torch.cuda.is_available() 
False
```

Может ли кто-то подсказать как правильно установить? Дополнительную информацию предоставлю если будет нужно, сразу не знаю что еще добавить.

[image: Небольшая сводка по системе]

Comment: Добавил изменения в пост. ОС - Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sh-tsang.medium.com/tutorial-cuda-cudnn-anaconda-jupyter-pytorch-installation-in-windows-10-96b2a2f0ac57

Вкратце:

1. Устанавливаем CUDA  https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
2. Устанавливаем cuDNN  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn
3. Устанавливаем https://pytorch.org/ (на самой странице выбор команды, для установки).
   [image: Вариант команды, для установки pytorch через pip]

Если был установлен обычный pytorch, то удаляем его. В результате что-то подобное должно быть:

```
(base) C:\Users\user>pip list | grep torch
STDIN
efficientnet-pytorch          0.7.1
torch                         1.13.1+cu116
torch-summary                 1.4.5
torchaudio                    0.13.1+cu116
torchgeometry                 0.1.2
torchsampler                  0.1.1
torchvision                   0.14.1+cu116
```